# Winforms Designer and C#, how to programmatically call what the "Default" property grid selection does

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, windows-forms-designer

In the Visual Studio Designer, I can change, say, the background of a textbox to blue.

To change it back to its 'default' value, I can right click on that property and click "Default Value".

My question: How do I do that programmatically?  I'd like the opportunity to set my controls to and from a custom color back to their windows default (without specifically knowing what they are).

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a generic way of doing that. You could produce a table of control types and their default background colors. It's typically either Control (buttons) or Window (textbox).

Comment: Unfortunately `BackColor` doesn't have a `DefaultValue` attribute as many of the other properties do have. I believe having a dictionary as @Steven suggests is reasonable. You might want to look at the [SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.aspx) class. As a start, the default background for textbox is `Window` I believe, and `WindowText` for the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/408870/719186) seems to do what you are looking for:

```
PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(textBox1)["BackColor"];
if (prop.CanResetValue(textBox1)) {
  prop.ResetValue(textBox1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can change any control's property 
or also you can see how it build your form via your designer class
check your `form1.designer.cs` 
and read it you can find every control's initialization there.

and if  you want to change ur textbox back color here is a code

```
   textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;
```

Comment: That wont work if the color isn't initially set (windows default value)

Comment: there is no any default back color if its not set then by default take form background color when you set `textbox.BackColor` its override color

Comment: and its a come from `abstract class TextBoxBase` .

Comment: As a for instance, if you drag a TextBox onto the winforms designer.  It has a white backcolor, and black forecolor.  If I change both of those, I'd like to get both of those values again.